# Action Bar Doesn't work correctly

Tags: java, android, android-activity, toolbar, appbar

I restarted to develop now after years so there were many changes.
Now I'm trying to modify the AppBar (Toolbar), for the activity. (I also see the CoordinatorLayout, but i don't know what differences have with the Linear and Relative).
So in the MainActivity.class i have:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    TextView mTitle = (TextView) 
    toolbar.findViewById(R.id.toolbar_title);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    mTitle.setText(toolbar.getTitle());
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);

    mTitle.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#ff0000"));
```

and in activity_main.xml:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/title"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:id="@+id/toolbar_title" />

        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/content_main" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

And it works fine, the color and the title (or it seems).

Then i also created two other activity (that i open from a button (i will explain one...they made similar problems):
SecondActivity.class:

```
public class ActivityMappa extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_mappa);

    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbarmappa);
    TextView mTitle = (TextView) toolbar.findViewById(R.id.toolbarmappa_title);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    mTitle.setText(toolbar.getTitle());
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);

    mTitle.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#ff0000"));
    toolbar.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#fafad2"));

}
```

and activity_second.xml:

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".ActivityMappa">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbarmappa"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/title_mappa"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:id="@+id/toolbarmappa_title" />

    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

In this second activity, the toolbar color it's right, but the text not change when i run the app (in the android studio preview it was changed), and the text it is in the @string/title_mappa and it exists.
So why the text does not change? The code is the same.

An other thing, when i add stuff in the content_main.xml, the position start under the Toolbar, and if i set the margin/padding, it starts from it, but from the other 2 activity, when i add other stuffs (like imageview), they starts from the app start at the top, above the toolbar, why?

Thank you so much for the help.

Comment: Provide the code where you are changing the text in the second activity

Comment: Was my answer succesful?

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is that you are setting the text of `toolbarmappa_title` to the title of `toolbarmappa` but the title of `toolbarmappa` is null therefore you are setting the text to null. You need to set the text with a predefined string or set the title of `toolbarmappa` before you get the title.

It would be something like this:

```
public class ActivityMappa extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_mappa);

    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbarmappa);
    TextView mTitle = (TextView) toolbar.findViewById(R.id.toolbarmappa_title);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    toolbar.setTitle("insert title here");
    mTitle.setText(toolbar.getTitle());
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);

    mTitle.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#ff0000"));
    toolbar.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#fafad2"));    
}
```

Also, general pratice to change the text of a toolbar is not to add a TextView. You can remove the TextView and call `toolbar.setTitle("insert text here");` and that eliminates the need of the TextView.

Comment: Ok i tried it, and for the title text  it works, but if i try toolbar.setTitletextColor(Color.parseColor(""));, it does not change

Comment: And if remove the TextView, no text will be explained

Comment: You need to input a color. For example, black is Color.parseColor("#000000") and white is Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF")

Comment: You can Google "hex color chooser" and choose a color and use the 6 character code with the `#` before it.